# Error compiling jni code with android-ndk-r10e

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

I'm having trouble compiling my jni code using android-ndk-r10e.

Inside the jni folder there is the main c code file **hello.c** and then there is another folder **includeLocal** where there is the **com_MyPackage_Hello.h** file inside. It used to compile fine with previous ndk versions but now I get this error:

```
 Error:error: unknown type name 'jobjectArrayJNICALL'
 JNIEXPORT jobjectArrayJNICALL Java_com_MyPackage_Hello_hello(
 ^
Error:error: conflicting types for 'Java_com_MyPackage_Hello_hello'
 JNIEXPORT jobjectArrayJNICALL Java_com_MyPackage_Hello_hello(
                               ^
Information:(Unknown) In file included
jni/includeLocal/Java_com_MyPackage_Hello.h:22:9: note: previous declaration of 'Java_com_MyPackage_Hello_hello' was here
         Java_com_MyPackage_Hello_hello(JNIEnv *, jobject, jbyteArray, jint, jint);
         ^
jni/hello.c: In function 'Java_com_MyPackage_Hello_hello':
Warning:warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
           return NULL; /* exception already thrown */
           ^
Warning:warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
            return NULL;
            ^
Warning:warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
          return ret;
          ^
```

any ideas how to fix this? I'm not very keen on ndk stuff.

Below is the h. file as well

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_MyPackage_Hello */

#ifndef _Included_com_MyPackage_Hello
#define _Included_com_MyPackage_Hello
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#undef com_MyPackage_Hello_MIN_PRIORITY
#define com_MyPackage_Hello_MIN_PRIORITY 1L
#undef com_MyPackage_Hello_NORM_PRIORITY
#define com_MyPackage_Hello_NORM_PRIORITY 5L
#undef com_MyPackage_Hello_MAX_PRIORITY
#define com_MyPackage_Hello_MAX_PRIORITY 10L
/*
 * Class:     com_MyPackage_Hello
 * Method:    hello
 * Signature: ([BI)[Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
        Java_com_MyPackage_Hello_hello(JNIEnv *, jobject, jbyteArray, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: You accidentally left out a space between `jobjectArray` and `JNICALL`?

Comment: @immibis I don't believe this You were right. It was android studio's fault when I did auto formating. The new NDK Support still sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently reformat-code option in android studio 1.3.2 is very dangerous for C/C++ stuff. It should have left a space on `jobjectArrayJNICALL` like this `jobjectArray JNICALL`

NDK support is still very limited in general.